# Can you use any footswitch on any amplifier?

Tags: amplifiers, electronics

For example, if I have an amplifier that comes with a 4-button footswitch (2 cables for this footswitch), can I use just any footswitch in the store with 2 buttons (1 cable) and just plug 2 2-button footswitches in the amplifier?

This is the amp:

http://www.ibanez.co.jp/world/manual/amp/TB100H.pdf

This is the original footswitch:

http://medias.audiofanzine.com/images/normal/ibanez-tb100h-196201.jpg

I hope to use a 2-button footswitch with guitar-style cabel to use the first two buttons?

Would that work?

Comment: Note that the lights are powered by the amp, so it is not a just a simple switch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No - you can't just use any footswitch with any amplifier.

Some footswitches are really simple - a make or break connection, but others do different things - sometimes voltage drops, sometimes active circuitry, sometimes polarity changes.

So while it may work, it may not, and in some circumstances you may be able to damage your amp (rare, but possible)

Comment: I didn't damage it while testing with Behringer footswitch, but it didn't work. I'll order the original - IFS4 ibanez

Comment: Generally, the make/break connections will utilize TSR jacks and a stereo cable, not a mono guitar cable.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot generally use a footswitch with another model.

Some are latching, meaning they stay in the position to which they're switched (either on or off).

Some are momentary, which mean they're only on while either depressed or released depending on the design.

Be especially careful with  Peavey footswitches between models.

Answer (score 1):

It APPEARS to be latching as the switches are 'old style' and should audibly click when pushed.The amp connections APPEAR to be 1/4" stereo jack so something like a Peavey double footswitch COULD work.Whether this would switch the 2 functions you need with one wire depends on the configuration of the amp wiring.Certainly one switch out of the two will switch one effect, say reverb or channel change, but with 4 options on the original, you may be lucky.Behringer sells a double control pedal with many switching options, that may serve your needs.

Comment: I actually ordered that one! :D It's coming tommorow so I'll test it.

Comment: It didn't work. :( I'll have to order the original one - IFS4 ibanez

Comment: Did you try all the functions, latching and momentary ?It's pretty comprehensive.

Comment: Ya, nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Some footswitches have a 1/4-inch monaural "telephone plug" connector, the same as the output connector on a conventional electric guitar.

Other footswitches have the same physical plug size but in the TRS (tip-ring-sleeve) configuration.

Other footswitches use a five-pin MIDI connector.

Still others use any of a number of different physical connector plugs. The wiring of the connection mechanism may be proprietary to the manufacturer. These may even include digital connectors.

You must identify the exact make and model of your amplifier, and you must find the instruction manual for the amplifier, which will explain the exact specifications of the footswitches that can be used with it. Then you can determine whether you must use a particular model of footswitch sold by the manufacturer of the amplifier, or if you can use another brand of footswitch made by a different manufacturer.

Comment: It's a guitar-style cable. I don't understand the manual. ibanez.co.jp/world/manual/amp/TB100H.pdf 
This is the original footswitch: 
medias.audiofanzine.com/images/normal/ibanez-tb100h-196201.jpg 

I hope I could use a 2-button footswitch with a guitar-style cable just to use these first 2 buttons?